# Angular routing - named views

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I started using Angular 4 and I'd like to use Angular router instead of ui router (mostly because of the CLI) which I was using with Angular 1.5 but there is one thing that I need and I don't see and that are named views.

If I am not wrong I could work around this by using componentless route with children:

```
{ 
  path: 'someRoute',
  children: [
     {
        path: '',
        component: ComponentOne,
        outlet: 'one'
     },
     {
        path: '',
        component: ComponentTwo,
        outlet: 'two'
     }
  ]
}
```

Then I need to set this route to be the parent of all other routes so they can override any outlet they want if they want (like with ui router named views), but I don't see how to do it without using only one routing module (because of a way of declaring hierarchy with nested routes). Am I missing some way to specify the parent route without nesting routes?

Is this possible or maybe there is a better way to do it?

Comment: I am facing the same problem, did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @toskv I found a workaround which was good enough for my problem. I don't use outlets but lazy loaded modules and multiple "layout compoennts" (one layout component with header and footer and one without). You can see how that can be done here https://stackblitz.com/github/jbojcic1/angular-routing-example?file=src%2Fapp%2Flayout%2Flayout-routing.module.ts

Comment: thanks for the example :)